# Is it possible to add a classname to each test case in assertion.xml using gatling?

Tags: testing, junit, assertions, gatling

I want to use the gatling junit report to upload it automatically in Testlink using Hudson but there is no classname tag in the file so I can't link it to a test case. Is there any way to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I don't need to change the junit file! I used the test suite name in testling as a custom field and I configured it in hudson with testlink plugin.